# $ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {n^2} =\frac {\pi ^2}{6} $ then $ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {(2n -1)^2} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, pi

If $ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {n^2} =\frac {\pi ^2}{6} 
 $ then $ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {(2n -1)^2} $

Dont know what kind of series is this. Please educate. 
How to do such problems?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2} =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{(2n)^2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{(2n-1)^2}=\frac14 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{(2n-1)^2}$$

So, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{(2n-1)^2}= \frac34 \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{8}$.

Comment: Ok.. How you understood that? Now it looks obvious. But how you got that intuition?

Comment: I say this is the secret of even numbers : They are twice the natural numbers !

Comment: Oh yes yes... A lil bit of explaination would have helped.. Not so fluent in maths..

Comment: shouldnt be $ \frac 3 4 * \frac 1 6 $ be $ \frac 1 8 $

Answer (score 1):

you can use the relation 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty   \frac{1}{(2n-1)^k}=(1-\frac{1}{2^k})\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^k}$$
when the $k$ even integer number($k\geq2) $

Comment: this should work for $k > 1$, integer or not

Comment: Is it true would you please provide some proof

Comment: @Soke this for $k=2,4,6,.....$