# Convergence of improper integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(x)}{1-x^2}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Find whether the integral converges or diverges.
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(x)}{1-x^2}dx$$

I simplified it to $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(x)}{(1-x)(1+x)}dx$$

Here I have $2$ "bad" bounds (both $0$ and $1$).

I think, to prove such integral converges, I should find something that is equivalent to or less than $\log(x)$ so I can exchange them, maybe $\sqrt{x}$, so it may cancel out the fraction, and I can compare it to $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x^p}$$

Also I had an idea to substitute $x$ with $u+1$ so I can use $\log(1+u) \sim  u$ when $u \rightarrow 0$. I'm allowed(not familiar with anything else) to use direct comparision test, limit comparision test, Cauchy test and Abel-Dirichlet's test.

Any hints are much appreciated, I just want to get the big picture.

Thank you.

Comment: It converges to $-\dfrac{\pi^2}8$

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align} \int _0^1 \frac{\log x}{\color{#08F}{1 - x^2}} dx &=  \int _0^1 \log x \Big( \color{#08F}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{2n}}\Big) dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \int _0^1 x^{2n}\log x dx \\&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\Bigg[\frac{x^{2n  +1}}{2n +1} \log x \Big|_0^1 -  \frac{1}{2n+1}\int _0^1 \frac{x^{2n+1}}{x} dx\Bigg]\\&=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}\\&= \color{red}{ -\frac{\pi^2}{8}}\tag{*}\end{align}$$

Where you may find why $(*)$ holds, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194009/sum-n-1-infty-frac-1-n2-frac-pi-26-then-sum-n-1-i/1194015#1194015).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I know your way is better, but I'm looking for analytical approach and conclusion, that this integral converges

Comment: It's analytical.

Comment: You're welcome, even though it's "not" what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As $x\to 1$, $${\log(x)\over 1 - x^2} = {\log(x)\over (1 + x)(1-x)}\sim
-{\log'(x) \over 2 } = -{1\over 2}$$
As $x\to 0$, 
$${\log(x)\over 1 - x^2}\sim \log(x),$$
which integrates at $0$.  The improper integral exists and is finite.

Comment: I didnt get the part why your 2 sides are equivalent, and how did you get it

Comment: I am using the notation $f \sim g$ as $x\to a$ if $f(x)/g(x) \to 1$ as $x\to a$.    This test tells you the integral converges.

Comment: well, I'm more interested in how to identify the right formula for g, rather than showing that they are in same order.

Comment: What was your question?